# Передача переменных из php в javascript без перезагрузки

Tags: javascript, html, php, html5

есть страничка :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/Global.css">
        <script src="JS/Librarie.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="Global();">
        <header id='Header'>
        </header>
        <aside id='AsideLeft'>

        </aside>
        <div id='Content'>
            <div id='Conteiner'>
                <div style='width: 100%; height: 100%; ' id='loader'>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Оброботчик броботчик:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include ("bd.php");

    if (isset($_COOKIE['auto']) and isset($_COOKIE['email']) and isset($_COOKIE['password'])) {
        if ($_COOKIE['auto'] == 'yes') {
            $_SESSION['password']=strrev(md5($_COOKIE['password']))."b3p6f";
            $_SESSION['email']=$_COOKIE['email'];
            $_SESSION['id']=$_COOKIE['id'];
            if (!empty($_SESSION['email']) and !empty($_SESSION['password'])) {
                $email = $_SESSION['email'];
                $password = $_SESSION['password'];
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password' AND activation='1'",$db); 
                $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                $email = $myrow['email'];
            }
        }   
    }

    if (!empty $email) {
        $menu = "
            <div class='Menu3'>
                Новости
            </div>  
            <div class='Menu3'>
                Друзья
            </div>
            <div class='Menu3'>
                Диологи
            </div>
            <div class='Menu3'>
                Фотографии
            </div>
            <div class='Menu3'>
                Настройки
            </div>
        "
    }else{
        $menu = "
            <div class='Menu3'>
                Войти
            </div>  
            <div class='Menu3'>
                Регистрация
            </div>
        "
    }
?>
```

Необходимо без перезагрузки страници связатся с оброботчиком и переменную $menu запихнуть
в 
    <aside id='AsideLeft'>

```
</aside>
```

пока что получяется что-то типо

```
    function getXmlHttp(){
      var xmlhttp;
      try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e) {
        try {
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (E) {
          xmlhttp = false;
        }
      }
      if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      return xmlhttp;
    }

        function Global() {
        var req = getXmlHttp();
        var statusElem = document.getElementById('AsideLeft');
        req.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // если запрос закончил выполняться
                statusElem.innerHTML = req.statusText // показать статус (Not Found, ОК..)
                if(req.status == 200) {
                    statusElem.innerHTML = req.responseText;
                     // если статус 200 (ОК) - выдать ответ пользователю
                }
                // тут можно добавить else с обработкой ошибок запроса
            }
        }
        req.open('GET', 'Formers.php', true); 
        req.send(null);  // отослать запрос
        statusElem.innerHTML = 'Ожидаю ответа сервера...'
}
```

Но нифега ни выходит :(((

Comment: Откройте для себя отладчик (в хроме он встроенный, а в ФФ нужно поставить FireBug) посмотрите что уходит в аякс реквесте и что приходит, и сразу всё станет ясно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В PHP-коде не вижу, чтобы результат присвоения `$menu` как-то использовался. Сам по себе он не выведется. Остальной код выглядит работоспособным, так что, думаю, проблема в этом.

Но если нет противопоказаний или цели разобраться в подкапотных деталях — не мучайте себя изобретением велосипедов, возьмите ту же [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). Вся портянка кода сведется к:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var target = $("#AsideLeft");
    target.text("Ожидаю ответа сервера…");
    $.get("Formers.php", function(data) {
        target.html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: А если переменных несколько и их нужно рассовыват в разные места ?

Comment: Или велосипедировать:

    // php: echo json_encode(array("foo" => "...", "bar" => "..."));
    $.getJSON("foo.php", function(data) {
        $("#foo").html(data.foo);
        $("#bar").html(data.bar);
    });

Или взять готовое решение для client-side темплейтов. jQuery templates, [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), тысячи их. Или вообще не темплейтинг, а data binding, типа [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) или, там, Backbone.js + Rivest.js.